# How to select columns based upon column value?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

My dataframe schema is as below:

```
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- ts_ms: long (nullable = true)
```

I want the schema to pick before or after bases upon the value of column("op")

So something like

```
root
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = false) //from before if col("op")==='D' else for after 
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = false) //from before if col("op")==='D' else for after 
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = false)
```

My current code is picking after but I need it conditional so that for delete events it can pick from after section.

```
dataFrame
      .select(from_confluent_avro(col("Value"), valueRegistryConfig) as 'value)
      .select("value.op", "value.after.*")
```

Before and After can have n number of fields with the same name. Beside before/after, I also want op field.

Possible 'op' field values are:

- c
- d
- u

Comment: Can you please provide sample values for op attribute ?

Comment: @AravindPalani Possible values are c, d, u i.,e create, delete, update

Comment: How many fields does before and after struct contains ? If possible can you update the schema ?

Comment: @AravindPalani Before and After can have n number of fields with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

With [ABRiS - Avro Bridge for Spark](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS) the following worked fine:

```
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_confluent_avro
dataFrame
  .select(from_confluent_avro(col("Value"), valueRegistryConfig) as 'value)
  .withColumn("value_after_before",
    when(col("value.op") === "d", col("value.before"))
      .otherwise(col("value.after")))
  .select("value.op", "value_after_before.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

`.select(when($"value.op" === "D", $"before.id").otherwise($"after.id"))`, etc.